# Reversing a null terminated string (C++)

Tags: c++, string

Have a few clarification questions about my code; the problem is reversing a null terminated string.

Here is the full code for reference: (compiles and runs)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void reverseString (char *str) {

    char *end = str;
    char temp;

    while (*end != '\0')
    {
        end ++;
    }
    end--;

    //swap
    while (str < end) {
        temp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end-- = temp;
    }
}

int main() {

    char str[] = "hello!";

    reverseString (str);
    cout << str;
}
```

---

```
while (str < end)
```

Is the statement above comparing the addresses of the pointers? Since str is a pointer and end is one as well, and a pointer contains the address, is it checking that that address of str is less than end?

---

```
*str++ = *end;
```

This line will dereference the value stored in end, and set that equal to the value of str. And then increment the pointer str?

Lastly, is the (worst case) time complexity *O(n)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first and the third question is yes. You have the variables the other way around in the second question (it is `str` that gets dereferenced, set, and then incremented, not the other way around). Specifically: both `str` and `end` get dereferenced (that's what the `*` operator does). And the dereferenced `str` gets set to the dereferenced `end`. Then `str` gets incremented.

Additionally, `reverseString()` will run off the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior, and a possible crash, if the passed-in string is empty. Additional code needs to be added there to handle that possibility, as an edge case.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I hope I'm not completely wrong, but for the line `*str++ = *end;`, should assignment operations be read from right to left? I understand dereferencing both as a priority (in terms of the order), but always thought of it as the value of end being assigned to str.

Comment: An assignment operation assigns the `rvalue` on the right-hand side of the expression to the `lvalue` on the left-hand side of the expression. Yes, this is `end` being assigned to `str`, which is not what you had in your question: "the value stored in end, and set that equal to the value of str" is interpreted as assigning str to end, or "end is set to the value of str". Completely backwards.

Comment: Ah okay that's really good to know. Was concerned for a second there thinking I had it backwards all this time. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you aren't using the STL? In particular, [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    char str[] = "hello!";
    std::reverse(str, str + std::strlen(str));
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is actually from Cracking the Coding Interview. I'm assuming that they wouldn't let you use the reverse function during a interview although that would be great ...